# Automate creation of graphs in Excel using VBA

Tags: excel, vba, dynamic, charts, automation

I'm currently doing a project where I want to automate the creation of charts in Excel. I have data tables in one sheet and I already managed to use VBA to create graphs from all tables. Since the sheet might be updated on a ongoing basis with more tables I want to extend my macro to be able to recognize this. I imagine that I need a set of rules for the sheet. Fx if I add a new title in cell in column A and color it, it knows when I run the macro that it should add another chart this time. Also I need a cell with some sort of "code" name for which type of chart it should apply.
My macro is fixed to the tables that I currently have in the sheet and I made it dynamic in case I add more columns (when I add 2022, 2023 etc). I'm curious to know if anyone have tried this before or have a qualified suggestion to how to solve this
Thank you very much!

```
    Sheets("tables").Select

    Dim xData As Range

    Range("C78", Range("C78").End(xlToRight)).Select
    Set xData = Selection.Cells
    
'---table1---
    Range("B79").Select
    Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlToRight)).Select
    Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlDown)).Select
    ActiveWorkbook.Names.Add Name:="table1Data", RefersToR1C1:= _
        "=Uddybet!R79C2:R82C7"
    ActiveWorkbook.Names("table1Data").Comment = ""

    ActiveSheet.Shapes.AddChart2(201, xlColumnClustered).Select
    ActiveChart.SetSourceData Source:=Range("table1Data")
    ActiveChart.FullSeriesCollection(1).XValues = xData
    ActiveChart.ChartTitle.Text = "1"

'---table2---
    Dim colCount As Byte
    
    Range("B79", Range("B79").End(xlToRight)).Select
    colCount = Selection.Cells.Count + 2
    
    Dim table2Data As Range
    
    Selection.Offset(0, colCount).Select
    Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlDown)).Select
    Set table2Data = Selection.Cells

    ActiveSheet.Shapes.AddChart2(201, xlColumnClustered).Select
    ActiveChart.SetSourceData Source:=table2Data
    ActiveChart.FullSeriesCollection(1).XValues = xData
    ActiveChart.ChartTitle.Text = "2"
    ActiveChart.Axes(xlValue).MaximumScale = 0.16
    
'---table3---
    Dim table3Data As Range
    
    table2Data.Select
    
    Selection.Offset(0, colCount).Select
    Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlDown)).Select
    Set table3Data = Selection.Cells

    ActiveSheet.Shapes.AddChart2(201, xlColumnClustered).Select
    ActiveChart.SetSourceData Source:=table3Data
    ActiveChart.FullSeriesCollection(1).XValues = xData
    ActiveChart.ChartTitle.Text = "3"
    ActiveChart.Axes(xlValue).MaximumScale = 0.18

'---table4---  
    Dim table4Data As Range
    
    table3Data.Select
    
    Selection.Offset(0, colCount).Select
    Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlDown)).Select
    Set table4Data = Selection.Cells

    ActiveSheet.Shapes.AddChart2(201, xlColumnClustered).Select
    ActiveChart.SetSourceData Source:=table4Data
    ActiveChart.FullSeriesCollection(1).XValues = xData
    ActiveChart.ChartTitle.Text = "4"
    ActiveChart.Axes(xlValue).MaximumScale = 0.2
   
End Sub
```

[image]

Comment: Post a picture of your Tables sheet if possible or create a dummy one and post it.

Comment: @ElioFernandes I have now updated with a picture showing an example of one of my series of tables. All series contain four tables

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe the best way is to start:

- converting the ranges to table objects, aka listobjects.
- create a table to control which charts to print, here named
  'TableChartControl', where you also have the type of chart, chart
  title and if is to print or not.

With this solution, you can add as many tables as you want and create only the desired charts!

[image]

```
Sub PrintCharts()
    Dim ws As Worksheet: Set ws = Sheets("Tables")
    Dim olControl As ListObject: Set olControl = ws.ListObjects("TableChartControl")
    Dim ol As ListObject
    Dim olCol As Byte
    Dim olColRng As Range, olRng As Range
    Dim aCell As Range
    
    Dim xt As Object
    Dim xtTypeValue As String
    Dim xtType As XlChartType
    Dim xtTitle As String
    
    ' clear table filters
    If olControl.AutoFilter.FilterMode Then olControl.AutoFilter.ShowAllData
    
    ' filter chart to be printed
    olCol = olControl.ListColumns("Print").Index
    olControl.Range.AutoFilter field:=olCol, Criteria1:="yes"
    
    ' check for visible rows
    On Error Resume Next
    Dim olRowsVisible As Integer
    olRowsVisible = olControl.ListColumns(1).DataBodyRange.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Count
    On Error GoTo 0
    
    ' copy only if any rows visible
    If olRowsVisible = 0 Then Exit Sub
    
    ' list of charts to be created
    olCol = olControl.ListColumns("TableName").Index
    Set olColRng = olControl.ListColumns(olCol).DataBodyRange.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)
            
    ' print charts
    For Each aCell In olColRng
        ' Select table
        Set ol = ws.ListObjects(aCell.Value)
        Application.GoTo ol.Range

        xtTypeValue = aCell.Offset(0, olControl.ListColumns("XlChartType").Index - 1).Value
        xtTitle = aCell.Offset(0, olControl.ListColumns("ChartTitle").Index - 1).Value
        
        ' type of chart
        Select Case xtTypeValue
            Case "xlLineMarkers": xtType = xlLineMarkers
            Case "xlLine": xtType = xlLine
            Case "xlColumnClustered": xtType = xlColumnClustered
            Case "xlColumnStacked": xtType = xlColumnStacked
        End Select

        ' Create chart
        ' https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.xlcharttype
        Set xt = ws.Shapes.AddChart2
        With xt.Chart
            .ChartType = xtType
            .ChartTitle.Caption = xtTitle
        End With
    Next aCell
    
    ' clear table filter
    If olControl.AutoFilter.FilterMode Then olControl.AutoFilter.ShowAllData
    
    ' clear
    Set xt = Nothing
    Set ol = Nothing
    Set olControl = Nothing
End Sub
```